# multiple colorbox issue in jquery , confirm box in one colorbox is appearing on other colorboxs unnecessary after click on close button

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have multiple colorbox in my home page .I have implemented a confirm box on one colorbox after click on  close button in colorbox .But Now I am getting some issue ,when I click on CONFIRM BOX and after that I will go to others colorbox and click on their close button ,,,,I am getting again same CONFIRM BOX unnecessary..Currently I am using following code for implementing CONFIRM BOX ...

```
onComplete:function () {
                $("#cboxClose").unbind();
      $("#cboxClose").click(function (e) {
                var response;
                var formChanged = localStorage.getItem("isFormChanged");
           if (formChanged == "true") {
                response = confirm('some changes have been made,Do you want to close this window? ');          
                  if(response) {
                   $.colorbox.close();
                   }else {
                   return

            }else{
              $.colorbox.close();
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use multiple instance of colorbox at once because every instance is appending to `document.body` nodes every time using the same ids, and this upon instantiation, which you can see with any browser developer tool;

you'd need to create the instance on the click & then destroy it on the close but that would not be very smooth at usage (expect lags)...

your best option is to rethink your page or find another plugin